# How to remove excel row in first excel based on data of second excel file pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have one type of excel file with school data such as address, school name, principals name and etc. And second type of excel file with address, school name,rating, nubmer of telephone and etc. The question is: how can I delete particular rows in first excel file based on addresses of second?

first excel file:

```
      Unnamed: 0  School                                         Address
0              0  Alabama School For Deaf           205 E South Street, Talladega, AL 35160
1              1  Helen Keller School               1101 Fort Lashley Avenue, Talladega, AL 35160
2              2  Tutwiler Prison                   1209 Fort Lashley Ave., Talladega, AL 35160
3              3  Alabama School Of Fine Arts       8966 Us Hwy 231 N, Wetumpka, AL 36092
```

second:

```
                             School_Name  ...     Address
0                       Pine View School  ...     0 Mp 1361 Ak Hwy, Dot Lake, AK 99737
1       A.D. Henderson University School  ...     1 168 3Rd Avenue, Eagle, AK 99738
2    School For Advanced Studies - South  ...     2 249 Jon Summar Way, Tok, AK 99780
3    Tutwiler                                     3 1209 Fort Lashley Ave., Talladega, AL 35160
```

the output must be:

```
      Unnamed: 0  School                                         Address
0              0  Alabama School For Deaf           205 E South Street, Talladega, AL 35160
1              1  Helen Keller School               1101 Fort Lashley Avenue, Talladega, AL 35160
3              3  Alabama School Of Fine Arts       8966 Us Hwy 231 N, Wetumpka, AL 36092
```

I tried to use for loop, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('US1234.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
data = []
data_schools = []
df = pd.read_excel('DZ13288pubprin.xlsx')
lists = [[] for i in range(2)]

states = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY',
          'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH',
          'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
print(len(states))


def checking_top_100(nameofschool):
    for i in states:
        df2 = pd.read_excel('TOP-100.xlsx', sheet_name=[i])
        for a in df2[i]['SchoolName']:
            if nameofschool in a:
                pass
            else:
                return nameofschool


def sort_by_value(state, index):
    for i in range(len(df.SchoolName)):
        if df.LocationState[i] == state:
            # print(df.SchoolName[i])
            school_name = checking_top_100(df.SchoolName[i])
            lists[index].append(school_name)
            lists[index].append(
                df.LocationAddress[i] + ', ' + df.LocationCity[i] + ', ' + df.LocationState[i] + ' ' + df.LocationZip[
                    i])
            # lists[index].append(df.EmailAddress[i])
    print(lists[index][0::2])


def data_to_excel(state, index):
    dfi = pd.DataFrame({
        'SchoolName': lists[index][0::2],
        # 'Principal Name': lists[index][1::3],
        # 'Email Address': lists[index][2::3],
        'Address': lists[index][1::2]

    })
    dfi.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=state)


# checking_top_100()
for i in range(len(states)):
    sort_by_value(states[i], i)
    data_to_excel(states[i], i)

writer.save()
```

Comment: So if I get this correctly you want to drop the address from DF1, if that address is in DF2?

Comment: @sophods not only address but whole row, but actually yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at pandas.DataFrame.isin (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html). As this would return a boolean array (True or False) depending on whether or not the address is found in the second dataframe, you could then simply use boolean indexing to filter out the subset of the data where the address is not found.

In other words, you could do something like:

`dataframe1[dataframe1.Address.isin(dataframe2.Address) == False]`

This should give you the result you want.